# Do I need an antivirus on a Minecraft server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus, minecraft

I'm about to open a dedicated server for a game called Minecraft. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2. The problem is, I don't know whether or not I should install an antivirus on it. No one will have access to it besides me and I won't be downloading anything on it, nor will there be any file transfers. Is an antivirus still required?

Answer (score 7):

Install it!

If your server is facing the internet and people can access it (to play the game), it means that 1 or more ports are open; it is therefore accessible to the outside world and 'open' to attack.

Ensure you have a good firewall and I would still recommend an AV!

**EDIT**

I have used ClamAV and it worked fine (and it is free) - I used it to monitor my all in one mail/web server. As it's free though don't expect the world (although you can pay for it for more features). It may be worth while starting with a free AV and seeing how you go, although my money would go straight on Kaspersky from the word go!

Comment: +1. If it is connected to the Internet and thus to lots of potential abusers: Keep it up to date. Use a firewall. Use a virus scanner.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what purpose an antivirus would serve (considering the OP specified there will be no file uploads/downloads)?

Comment: @Indrek - I think you raise a good point, may be I'm just following best practices! If some one can get on then the other server then they could do anything (which could also include turning off the AV I must admit); However, if OP is hosting then files will be written /installed (eg the game needs to be installed) then it means files are being installed and IMO (no offence to OP) that the OP *may* not have realized what will be required. Further more, if the server is in a datacenter, it is on a network with other machines; I agree it should be locked down, but a network is exploitable!

Comment: All files will be scanned and tested on my PC Before being uploaded

Comment: @Patrick Although I find it hard to argue against Indrek (who I expect is just playing devil's advocate to ensure the answer is good as possible), I would still do it. Please note, your server is in a data center, with other computers on its local network - even a corrupted employee could stick a virus on the network! Although this type of argument is probably so over the top for your question. I stand by my opinion, do it but can't justify it 100%!

Comment: While Indrek has a decent point if your virus scanner is a plain virus scanner I still recommend installing it, updating it and doing an automated (daily/weekly) scan. I agree nothing bad *should* get onto the server. I've also seen reality.

Comment: @DaveRook "*who I expect is just playing devil's advocate to ensure the answer is good as possible*" That, and I was also personally curious about whether a game server has different security requirements than, say, a web or mail server (which definitely do need a virus scanner). Also, it should probably be mentioned that most antivirus products refuse to install on a Windows Server OS unless you buy an expensive enterprise version (or muck around with the installer, which may eventually produce more problems than it solves).

Comment: @Indrek - Agreed; FYI ClamAV is free and works for Windows Server (which I used on 2003 and 2008) (may be now called Immunet).

Comment: @DaveRook I've no experience with ClamAV, but it's good to know there are free options (assuming it's any good, of course; a bad AV is no better than no AV, as it just instills a false sense of security). My 2008 R2 home server is currently running without an AV (apart from the built-in Windows Defender), but it's also not publicly accessible.

Comment: If it was my server, I'd pay and not use a free one, however, they do exist! :)  @Patrick, hopefully this helps a little to see that, as a general rule even if you don't *need* the AV, get it :) And get a good one!

Comment: @Everyone Thanks for the help all i will follow advice and pay for a full version antivirus, Happy holidays all!!

Comment: @Patrick Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark outline next to it) if it helped you. And happy holidays to you as well.